# Pattern/Regular expression to grab a number *only* if it's the only field in the record

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, java.util.scanner, regex-lookarounds

This has been driving me crazy the past couple of days. I'm trying to kill two birds with one stone by validating a record and extracting a field at the same time. My strategy has been to do this with a regular expression:

```
private Pattern firstNumber = Pattern.compile("\\d{1}");
```

Which I understand to mean "the first number in the line (record)." So far this has been effective at grabbing the first field (and ensuring that it's a number), but I want to take this a step further:

**How can I tweak the regexp to specify that I want the number only if it's the sole field?**

That is, if the record is simply `10`, I want to grab 10. But if the record is `10 4`, I don't want to grab anything (as this is an invalid record for the project).

I tried:

```
private Pattern oneNumberOnly = Pattern.compile("\\d{1}\n");
```

But -- to my chagrin -- this (and any other permutation of it) does not pick up *any* numbers. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Can your record still contain other things but numbers? Or do you really only want to match if there is one number in the line and nothing more?

Comment: For this "read mode," I'm looking only for records consisting of a single number. There are other modes (for instance where want the first field to be a number, and the second field to be "Win" "Loss" or "Tie"), but I figured I'd cross that bridge when I got to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can denote beginning of line/string with `^` and end of line/string with `$`, so the pattern would be

```
^\d+$
```

The `{1}` won't work because it excludes anything with more than one digit, such as 10. Using `\d+` indicates one or more digits. Using `\d` may also allow decimals and negative values (not sure about Java), so if you only want digits, replace `\d` with `[0-9]`.

Specifying `{1}` is always redundant, by the way, because by default an atom is matched once.

Comment: +1, more specifically, `{1}` is like saying "appears exactly once" and has nothing to do with position.

Comment: @Brian Good point. Yes, if the thought was that `{1}` referred to the first instance, that is incorrect. The curly braces are used to denote the number of occurrences to match. `{3}` is exactly 3, `{3,}` is 3 or more, `{3,5}` is at least 3 and no more than 5.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Jay. I'm still having trouble. When I implement `Scanner in = new Scanner(File);` and try to call `in.hasNext("^[0-9]+$");` I get `false` returned, even when I use a correct test file

Comment: @user1209326 What does a typical line of the file look like?

Comment: @Jay Just a `3` (really, `3\n` to be exact). The regex *wont* grab anything from `5 10` -- which is good -- but it also won't grab `3` in the aforementioned case

Comment: @user1209326 Might there be any whitespace around the `3`?

Comment: @Jay just the newline character immediately after the `3` Nothing before it. Does the $ account for the /n?

Comment: @user1209326 Typically a RegEx applies to a single line, but depending on the RegEx engine, one can enable certain options. In .NET there is a SingleLine option where newlines are basically ignored. Unfortunately, I don't know the details of Java's engine.

Comment: @Jay that's alright, you've really helpful already. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the start line character and end line character. If you are trying to grab a number that is on its own line you can use:

```
Pattern.compile("^(\\d)++$");
```

By adding the {1} you will only get 1 digit of a number. You should also trim the string you are comparing against to get rid of any extra whitespace.

- `^` - Start of line character
- `\\d` - digit character [0-9]
- `+` - 1 or more characters that match \d
- `+` - possesive (this will grab all the digits and is quicker than greedy quantifiers)
- `$` - End of line character